# Debian. Пропал звук после смены жесткого диска

Tags: debian, аудио

На ноутбуке HP pavilion 7170er давненько была установлена Debian

На днях временно поменял винт на другой, потом вернул старый, с Debian

Результат - пропал звук. Пробовал баловаться с ползунками Alsamixer - безрезультатно

При попытках ввода команды

```
apt-get install alsa alsa-lib alsa-base alsa-util libdssialsacompat0
```

Вот что получаю на экране

[image]

SoundManager вообще не определяет ни одно устройство[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, решение вопроса

Answer (score 1):

Решилось

В ноутбуках серии HP Pavilion в Bios есть вкладка System Configuration. Видимо, при смене жесткого диска сбились ключи

Помог сброс ключей и возврат к заводским

Еще на всякий случай установил Enabled напротив Internal Network Adapter Boot